# Demorgans theorem confusion

Tags: boolean-algebra

In demorgan's theorem we were taught on three steps to achieve the answer

First step is to not all inputs

If the given is $ab$ then $(a)'(b)'$

Second step is to change the sign opposite to the current sign. From or to and and vice versa.

$(a)'+(b)'$

And lastly, simply not the final answer.

$((a)'+(b)')'$

If this is wrong please tell me. If not please proceed below.

So for exmaple the given is:

$ab + c$

Will I simply not the first term or not a and not b

$(ab)'$ or $((a)'(b)')$ ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thanks for the info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the fast answer is that you right (ab)'. if things like that confuse you the easiest way (at least for me) is to set e=ab and now you got e+c which you know to equivalent to (e'c')' and than you can exchange back to
$$ (e'c')'=((ab)'c')'=((a'+b')c')'$$